# Scripting Log On To Attribute in Active Directory

Tags: vbscript, adsi

I pasted this script into a .vbs file and ran it our domain controller (with our username, ou, and domain info):

```
Set objUser = GetObject _
  ("LDAP://cn=Ken Myer,ou=Finance,dc=fabrikam,dc=com")

objUser.Put "userWorkstations", "atl-ws-01,atl-ws-02,atl-ws-03"
objUser.SetInfo
```

And receive the error:

> No such user object on the server.

However, I've double checked the username, ou, and domain several times.  Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: The code should work. Not much we could do without seeing your real code. What do you get when running `WScript.Echo TypeName(objUser)` and `WScript.Echo objUser.sAMAccountName`? Did you make sure the protocol specifier (`LDAP://`) is in all-caps?

Answer (score 0):

if you install [adsiedit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773354%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) it will help you get the appropriate LDAP string to use. it's easy to get tripped up with this stuff, so i'd verify that the object you're looking for really **is** located where you think it is.

for instance, i open adsiedit.msc (by `ctrl+r adsiedit.msc enter`) right click, choose connect to. then under computer i choose default. then i hit ok.

i can then dig around the folder structure of AD for the object (person) i'm looking for.
in my AD Schema, my user account can be navigated to using `LDAP://CN=greenierb,OU=TSG,OU=Users,OU=Accounts,OU=Boston,OU=Offices,DC=domain,DC=com`

which is the reverse of the folder structure you navigate through in adsiedit (from the bottom of the hierachy (ie the user) up).

Comment: You don't need `Adsiedit` for this. In `AD Users and Computers` enable advanced features (in the `View` menu) and you'll get a tab `Attribute Editor` in the user's properties, which will list all attributes including the distinguished name.